# Download a file from Node.js using Express.js and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, routing-controllers

I work on a REST API using Node, Express and TypeScript. I want to write a controller for downloading a file from the server. The filename is saved in a database alongside its extension, path, etc. The id is given as request parameter. Somehow I can't manage to make it work, after trying `res.download()` and other solutions. Here is my code:

```
@Get('/:uuid/download')
async downloadFile(@Param('uuid') uuid: string, @Res() res: Response) {
    const result = await this.fileService.getFileById(uuid);
    if (result !== undefined) {
        const file = join(result.path, result.name + result.extension);
        res.download(file);
        return res;
    } else {
        return res.status(404).json({message: 'File not found'});
    }
}
```

I get no error in logger and a  "Cannot GET /api/file/some-uuid/download" in browser. I tried with a local file from the working directory but again with no success.
Also, I tried other solutions and I keep getting this error:

```
error:   - Error
at NotFoundError.HttpError [as constructor] (C:\Users\Teo\Desktop\projects\cyberbox\back\node_modules\routing-controllers\http-error\HttpError.js:31:23)
at new NotFoundError (C:\Users\Teo\Desktop\projects\cyberbox\back\node_modules\routing-controllers\http-error\NotFoundError.js:24:28)
at ExpressDriver.handleSuccess (C:\Users\Teo\Desktop\projects\cyberbox\back\node_modules\routing-controllers\driver\express\ExpressDriver.js:316:23)
at C:\Users\Teo\Desktop\projects\cyberbox\back\node_modules\routing-controllers\RoutingControllers.js:136:61
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
```

If someone know or has any idea, would save me for days of struggle. Thank you!

Comment: Is `result` undefined? Add a `console.log`.

Comment: @cbr no, the result is ok, the record is fetched from the database accordingly. I consoled log it and it seems ok.

Comment: Did you try simply call `fs.readFileSync(file)` to test is a file is readable or not?

Comment: @Anatoly yup, tried right now, it reads it without problems.